# Ansible ERROR: listen is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler

Tags: ansible

Below is my code.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: run command
    shell: uname
    register: result
    when: result.stdout== "Linux"
    notify: Create Directory

  handlers:
  - name: create a new new directory
    command: mkdir /home/ubuntu/ansible/new_dir
    listen: Create Directory
```

getting error while running:
ERROR: listen is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler

Comment: use `file` module instead of `command` to create directory

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change):

> As of Ansible 2.2, handlers can also “listen” to generic topics, and tasks can notify those topics as follows...

Please upgrade to Ansible 2.2+

Answer (score 0):

```
notify: Create_Directory

handlers:
      - name: Create_Directory
        file:
          path: /etc/some_directory
          state: directory
```

`notify: Create_Directory` and the handler's name should be equal. use `file` module instead of `command` to create directory